# Обработка нажатия в браузере

Tags: javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти обработчик клика в браузере вместо onClick, чтобы
в написанной мною игре "Жизнь" можно было закрашивать клетки ведением мыши, после нажатия в каком-либо месте поля.

```
function Square(props) {
    return (
        <button
            className="square"
            style={{background: props.isSelected ? "palevioletred" : "#fff"}}
            onClick={props.onClick}/>
    );
}
```

Так выглядит поле

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как сделано ваше поле? Если каждая клетка это отдельный элемент, вы можете задать им обработчик [onMouseOver](https://learn.javascript.ru/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave) или onMouseEnter. И менять цвет клетки при наведении на нее курсора мышки.

И отслеживать эти события, только если работает onMouseDown.
То есть если мышка нажата (onMouseDown), то закрашивать клетки на которые наводится курсор(onMouseOver).